# clear form element values within specific div or span using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to clear form elements value within specific div using jQuery, i have more than 25 fields in my form, i need function which is clear all type of form elements value. I tried with the basic jQuery function

`$('#div_id input[type="text"]').val('');`

Comment: `$('#div_id *').val('');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi you can use the below code to solve your problem, I hope it is working

```
function clear_form_elements(id_name) {
  jQuery("#"+id_name).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'file':
        case 'select-one':       
            jQuery(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For all kind of input fields(including select and textarea) try the [:input-selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

```
$('#div_id :input').val('');
```

Your selector will clear only those `input` element which as an explicit `type="text"` set, meaning `<input name="abc" />` will not be cleared